# When using Moq Verify() method invocation count, have failing test's error message contain actual method invocation count using Moq

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq, moq-3

Consider the following, where I am testing that an injected dependency's method is called a specific number of times:

```cs
[Fact]
public void WhenBossTalksEmployeeBlinksTwice()
{
    // arrange
    var employee = new Mock<IEmployee>();
    employee.Setup(e => e.Blink());

    var boss = new Boss(employee.Object);

    // act
    boss.Talk();

    // assert
    employee.Verify(e => e.Blink(), Times.Exactly(2)); // Passes as expected
    employee.Verify(e => e.Blink(), Times.Exactly(1)); // Fails as expected
}
```

When I force the failing test, the output is:

> Moq.MockException: Invocation was not performed on the mock 1 times: e
>   => e.Blink()

What would be better is something like:

> Moq.MockException: Invocation was unexpectedly performed 2 times, not 1 time: e
>   => e.Blink()

Here are the items involved with the test:

```cs
public interface IEmployee { void Blink(); }

public class Boss {
    private readonly IEmployee _employee;
    public Boss(IEmployee employee) { _employee = employee; }

    public void Talk() {
        _employee.Blink();
        _employee.Blink();
    }
}
```

**Is it possible to harvest and display the actual number of times the dependency's method was called, in the failing test's error message?**

I'm not sure that it matters, but I'm using Moq v3.1.416.3 (not the latest, I know, but another library I'm using hasn't updated to Moq 4.x yet…)

Comment: +1 for the example code :)

Comment: Since I found this in my googling, I thought I would provide an update. In Moq v4.1 (and maybe in all 4.x) you get something like: "expected invocation on the mock once but was 0 times". So the answer to this question is now out of the box.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't know of a straight way to harvest the information in Moq3.
What I would do is use a callback on the setup of Blink.

```cs
int count = 0;
employee.Setup(e => e.Blink()).Callback(() => count++);

...
employee.Verify(e => e.Blink(), Times.Exactly(1), "Moq.MockException: Invocation was unexpectedly performed " + count + " times, not 1 time: e => e.Blink()"); // Fails as expected
```

Comment: great idea! do you do something different when you personally use Moq 4.x?