# C# Moq Intercept method call

Tags: c#, moq

I'm not sure if what I want to do is possible. I have an interface that looks like this:

```
public interface IObject
{
     void MethodA(ObjectA arg1);
     void MethodB(ObjectB arg1, ObjectC arg2);
     void MethodC(ObjectD arg1, ObjectE arg2);
}
```

I have somthing like the following implementation:

```
public class ObjectImplementation : IObject
{
     public void MethodA(ObjectA arg1)
     {
          if(arg1.Something)
          {
               MethodB(new ObjectB(arg1), new ObjectC(arg1));
          }
          else
          {
               MethodC(new ObjectD(arg1), new ObjectE(arg1));
          }
     }
}
```

I'm trying to write a unit test to test if those calls to methodB or methodC are being made according to the condition I have. How something like that can be achieved?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693078/when-using-moq-verify-method-invocation-count-have-failing-tests-error-messa) seems relevant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to mock an interface and verify an implementation of this interface.

You could make methods C and D virtual and use the implementation in the mock.

**Implementation:**

```
public class ObjectImplementation : IObject
{
    public void MethodA(ObjectA arg1)
    {
        if (arg1.Something)
        {
            MethodB(new ObjectB(arg1), new ObjectC(arg1));
        }
        else
        {
            MethodC(new ObjectD(arg1), new ObjectE(arg1));
        }
    }

    public virtual void MethodB(ObjectB arg1, ObjectC arg2)
    {

    }

    public virtual void MethodC(ObjectD arg1, ObjectE arg2)
    {

    }
}
```

**Test:**

```
[Fact]
public void Test_WhenSomethingIsTrue_MethodB_Invoked_WithObjects_B_And_C()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<ObjectImplementation> mockObject = new Mock<ObjectImplementation>();
    ObjectA arg = new ObjectA();
    arg.Something = true;

    // Act
    mockObject.Object.MethodA(arg);

    // Assert
    mockObject.Verify(o => o.MethodB(It.Is<ObjectB>(b=> b.Arg == arg), It.Is<ObjectC>(c => c.Arg == arg)));
}

[Fact]
public void Test_WhenSomethingIsFalse_MethodC_Invoked_WithObjects_D_And_E()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<ObjectImplementation> mockObject = new Mock<ObjectImplementation>();
    ObjectA arg = new ObjectA();
    arg.Something = false;

    // Act
    mockObject.Object.MethodA(arg);

    // Assert
    mockObject.Verify(o => o.MethodC(It.Is<ObjectD>(d => d.Arg == arg), It.Is<ObjectE>(e => e.Arg == arg)));
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks! I only dislike the fact that I have to turn the method virtual, but that's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Well why can't you simply fake that method stub like

```
Mock<IObject> m = new Mock<IObject>();
m.Setup(x => s.MethodB(new ObjectB(arg1), new ObjectC(arg1)))
 .Callback(() => Console.WriteLine("MethodB Called"));
```

Thus if your condition `if(arg1.Something)` satisfies then the mocked one will be called and you will know

Answer (score 0):

While accepted solution should work I would strongly advise you against such kind of tests. Each method call results in some output and some side effects. So, if there is no output and no side effects then method simply does nothing. By asserting which MethodB or MethodC was called you don't check MethodA's output neither it's side effects. Such tests are brittle as they test only one possible *implementation* of MethodA not what it actually *does*. By brittle I mean the following:

suppose you have following implementation of IObject

```
class ObjectImpl
{
    public void MethodA(ObjectA arg1)
    {
        if (arg1.Something)
        {
            MethodB(new ObjectB(arg1), new ObjectC(arg1));
        }
        else
        {
            MethodC(new ObjectD(arg1), new ObjectE(arg1));
        }
    }

    public void MethodB(ObjectB arg1, ObjectC arg2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} and {1}", arg1, arg2);
    }

    public void MethodC(ObjectD arg1, ObjectE arg2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Bye {0} and {1}", arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

So, essentially MethodA just prints "Hi" or "Bye" to the console. Then if somebody will notice that MethodB and MethodC won't used anywhere except MethodA he may just remove them. Notice that MethodA is still the same so nothing gets broken except test.

```
class ObjectImpl
{
    // Everything works as before except broken build
    public void MethodA(ObjectA arg1)
    {
        if (arg1.Something)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hi {0} and {1}", new ObjectB(arg1), new ObjectC(arg1));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bye {0} and {1}", new ObjectD(arg1), new ObjectE(arg1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up implementing the accepted solution with tests to check if the the input and output parameters would be as expected. Still they won't test all the things that could happen inside MethodB, but there is already unit tests for that function.